# Intellij Idea line break after closing html tag

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

I have a problem with code formatting in Intellij Idea 12.1.6.
My issue regards breaking lines like that:

```html
<div class="underline">R</div>eject
```

The above line after applying code formatting is formated like that:

```html
<div class="underline">R</div>
eject
```

I have looked through Idea's code style settings but have not found any relevant setting.

Have anyone has any idea which setting is responsible for such formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested that the following changes the behavior as per your requirements:

(The numbers in the following steps map to the numbers in the screenshot)

1. Go into Intellij IDEA Settings -> Code Style (1) -> HTML (2) -> Other (3)
2. Then, under `Don't break if inline content` add 'div' by clicking on (4) and then (5).

After that attempting to format your code snippet does not push down `extent` into the next line.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Sorted out. I was nearly sure that I tested that setting but not. Thank you very much.